# calling .each{} on IntRange returns the range not each integer

Tags: groovy, int, range, each

I think I've got some funny expectations...  I want to iterate the numbers from 1 to 10. As a while loop it goes like this:

```
def countMe = 1
while (countMe<11) {
  println countMe
  countMe++
}
```

I was expecting that the following would do this also:

```
[1..10].each { println it }
```

But it actually prints the `IntRange`, not each `Integer` in the range.  What is the (syntactically) closest way to my `[x..y].each{}` fantasy to get each of a list of numbers?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

[Use parentheses not brackets:](http://ideone.com/dytPF)

```
(1..10).each{println it}
```

`[1..10]` is a list of length 1 containing a single range.

Comment: You need to remember [1..10] only means a range when it's a subscript AFTER another variable. When it stands alone, then it's a LIST OF a range. These little inconsistencies arise because Groovy tries hard to extend Java's syntax with its own additions.